# Flasher relay wiring diagram help

Tags: relay

[image]

This is a diagram for a flashing relay. Normally used for automotive, I'm curious if I can get it to work for my needs.

I want to be able to start and continue the flasher with a 12 V output, and while that output is on, flash a light bulb with a separate 12 V supply.

Is that possible with this type of relay?

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can tell this flasher must be powered from the same supply that runs the lamps.

if you want to use a different supply for the lamps you could have the flasher operate a relay use the relay to switch the lamp circuit

Comment: Thanks for the input. I wanted to avoid using a 2nd relay if I could. I can easily use a 2 pin flasher to drive another single pole relay if it's really necessary.

Comment: You need to operate it within its normal load rating or it should go to 2X its flashing rate as it is in fault mode.